# rm a corrupt file

Tags: rm, filesystem-corruption

I am trying to remove a file using rm. However, if I do ls, all the information about the file is ?????? ?? ?? example.txt... And calling rm returns that no such file exists. How can I force a remove of the file?

Comment: The questionmarks could also mean your file name contains characters your terminal can not display. Does ls -lha provide more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try: 
`rm -f example.txt`

Or
`touch example.txt && rm -f example.txt` (update timestamp on the file first)

Or
`chmod 777 example.txt && rm -f example.txt` (set readable, writeable, executable then remove it).

As suggested above, `fsck` is a good idea as well.

Comment: Someone care to explain why this answer is -1?

Comment: Don't know. I can see nothing wrong with it. I upvoted, but it should be at 1 now...

Comment: Did any of those fix your problem? Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the filesystem used, but most of the time you need to check the filesystem with fsck (the variant of it, whatever your filesystem is).